# ffmpeg RTSP to RTMP - Syntax error when running in Python 3

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert one of my CCTV RTSP streams to RTMP so I can add it onto a website. I've read many articles and understand that ffmpeg for Ubuntu 18.04 is the way to go.

I my script I've added the following code into Python 3.7:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://xx.xxx.xx.x:554/user=admin&password=123@&channel=1&stream=0.sdp" -f flv -r 25 -s 640x480 -an "rtmp://localhost:1935/uid/1/camera1"
```

but I get a syntax error in the quote mark at the end of the first link (rtsp link) I've searched for hours and can't see what anyone has mentioned this before. I've also reviewed the ffmpeg documentation and can't see any issues.

Please can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: What do you do to execute this command? Do you  use `os.system`? Can you show the line in your code where you call this command? And the error you got?

Comment: Thanks, for now I'm just testing in python, by going in PuTTy console, entering "Python3" then the above command - just to test, but then it will go into a script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment, you can't do it like this, since you can't directly execute commands from Python.

The simplest way to do it is by using `os.system`:

```py
import os
os.system('ffmpeg -i "rtsp://xx.xxx.xx.x:554/user=admin&password=123@&channel=1&stream=0.sdp" -f flv -r 25 -s 640x480 -an "rtmp://localhost:1935/uid/1/camera1"')
```

Be careful, you either have to use single quotation marks as I did, or to escape double quotation marks.

A cleaner way to do it may use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), to redirect `stderr` and `stdout` into Python variables for instance.

Comment: Brilliant, that seems to have fixed the initial problem and I'll look at subproces too. I now have "[rtsp @ 0x55a952847940] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP" adn when I use VLC to connect to rtmp://localhost:1935/uid/1/camera1 there is nothing there. But this is another issue so I'll need to read more into this